# Retrieving Preselected value in Struts 2 from Javascript

Tags: javascript, struts2

I am trying to access the value of a radio button which is already preselected in the form from Javascript but facing issue. In the form there are 2 set of radio buttons holding True and False each. Below is a rough diagram.

```
   O T   O F
   O T   O F
```

Now when the user selects the first radio button to false then second set of radio button is visible. Now the user chooses any values from the second set of radio button and navigates to first set of radio button and choose T. Now when the user clicks on false a javascript is getting called. In that I need to fetch radio button which is preselected already for the second set of radio buttons.

The preselected value I need to get it in Javascript for second set of radio button.

Code:

```
<s:radio id="id1" name="name1" list =${'T':'True',' F':'False'}>
<s:radio id="id2" name="name2" list =${'T':'True' 'F':'False'}>
```

I tried using `document.getElementById("id2").value;` in javascript but it doesn't give me result i.e. the preselection done in radio button for the second set, as Struts creates different id when it transforms to HTML.

How do I get the preselected value in Javascript for 2nd set of radio button ?

Comment: You have multiple radio buttons they cannot have same id. Use some other selector. Also your select tag syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Utilising `getElementByID()` is fine as a method of retrieving the value you're after.

Struts2 shouldn't automatically be generating your HTML-DOM IDs unless you are using struts form tags, if so then their id is determine by form parameters.  Else it's probably on your code for the jsp of the view(page).
Would need to see your jsp code to help, but recommend looking at the .jsp for the page to determine what ID you should look for with `getElementByID()`

Comment: As mentioned earlier in the question I need to retrieve the second set of radio button what the user has already selected in the jsp page. once the user click on True for the first set of radio button the second radio set gets hidden. Now the user clicks on False for the first set of Radio Button then user should see whatever he chose before in the second set of radio button earlier. This can be done by calling javascript. I am trying to fetch value from<s:radio > for secondset but unable to get  data in javascript. How do I get the preselected value from STRUTS2 radio button in Javascript.

Comment: Okay, so you're using the Struts2 form tags, this is why I asked to see the jsp code.

The id generated for <s:radio> will be `formaction`_`object`_`property` replacing the segments with those used by your form.
See: [Struts2 Documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-2-form-tags.html)

Your other option is to explicitly generate the form yourself in html in the .jsp file for your view, this way you can make the id whatever you want, however you will lose some struts tag features like iteration.

Comment: You could also work out the generated id just by inspecting the output html and then put that value into your 'getElementById()' call

Comment: *Struts2 shouldn't automatically be generating your HTML-DOM IDs* - Why not? It is a good practice to have an id.

Comment: Sorry, I meant unless struts form tags were being used, have edited original answer. You are correct, ids are good practice.

Comment: function onchangeRadio1(value){
var id2 = document.getElementById("id2").value;
if(id2=='F'){
showspan(true,'abcspan');
else
showspan(false,'defspan');
}


JSPCODE

<table>
<tr>
<td class="cellLabelDarkLeftJustifiedTop" >
VALUE1  RADIO1
<s:radio id="id1" name="id1" list="#{'T':'Yes','F':'No' }" onclick="onchangeRadio1(this)" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="cellLabelDarkLeftJustifiedTop" >
VALUE2  RADIO2
<s:radio id="id2" name="id2" list="#{'T':'Yes','F':'No' }" onclick="onchangeRadio2(this)" />
</td>
</tr>

</table>

Comment: Requirement:
When the user clicks on first radio button and click on 'F' then the user should see the second radio button. Now the user click on 'T' or 'F' and clicks on 'T' for 1st radio button the 2nd radio 
button becomes invisible.. Now user clicks on 'F' of the 1st radio button the second radio button what the user has preselected would appear. 


Issue:

I am not able to get the value of 2nd radio button value in the javascript using document.getElementById("id2").value what the user has selected previously.

How do I achieve it ..?